# Add ui:param according to all elements of JSF table

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jstl

```
<h:dataTable id="accountsOptions"
            value="#{account.mainOptions}" var="mainOption">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{mainOption.name}"/>
            </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

I needs in `ui:param` which will contains value of all columns of this table. How I can do this? Without js/jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote custom function in Java, which parses MainOptions and returns necessary string.

```
<h:dataTable id="accountsOptions"
            value="#{account.mainOptions}" var="mainOption">
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{mainOption.name}"/>
            </h:column>
            <ui:param name="options" value=#{cf:formatMainOptions(mainOption)}/>
</h:dataTable>
```